# String comparison not working as expected

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Here is the code:

```
response = line.split( '|' )
MyUtil.output "Inside loop@" + response[0] + "@"
FidelioUtil.output response[0].eql? 'LS' # .chomp.strip
```

and here is the output:

```
Sat Mar 03 08:55:36 +0000 2012: Inside loop@LS@
Sat Mar 03 08:55:36 +0000 2012: false
```

This does not appear to be working the way I expected. What is missing?

I have also tried chomp and strip but this doesn't appear to be helping.

Also "to_str" doesnt work either.

Any diagnosis code I can run on this variable so that I can see why it would not be comparing it properly?

Comment: What is the code doing exactly?

Comment: What you see in your output is the string representation of response[0]. There may be invisible characters or a different encoding especially when reading from external files. Did you check that?

Comment: How do I check for those chars?

Comment: Try `response[0].encoding` if you are using Ruby 1.9. Maybe a `response[0].inspect` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was hidden characters in the string. Using response[0].encoding and response[0].inspect helped.